# Stuck ignition on a 2010 Ford Focus

Tags: ignition, focus

I am no longer able to start my 2010 Ford Focus. The key is not able to turn at all.

Importantly, the car beeps when I open the driver side door as if the key was still in the ignition. This has happened before, but I would simply reinsert and remove the key. Then I would feel/hear something mechanically click into place and the beeping would stop. The problem is I can't make the click happen this time.

Any suggestions? What part will need to be replaced?

Comment: I'm sure you've tried this, but have you tried turning the steering wheel when trying to turn the key?

Comment: Yes, but couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Could be your key is extremely worn or the ignition lock cylinder is extremely worn. I suggest calling a local locksmith to replace key and code a new lock cylinder to oem biting for your car. Ford ignition locks are common failures.

You could also try flushing it out with some wd40 but it would be a temporary fix at best.

Answer (score 0):

Often the dust cover fails to close leaving the key hole exposed and this causes the issue described.

Sometimes a **tiny** bit of lubrication is sufficient (clean first) and then the cover closes smartly.

Comment: There are no dust covers on focus ignition locks. Just external locks will have them. Only things inside the ignition that could make clicking sound would be the key buzzer or one or more wafers. Considering the door chime, its likely the key buzzer is/was getting stuck.

Comment: @narkeleptk Ford have put dust covers on ignition locks.

Comment: There are no NA Fords to my knowledge with dust covers on ignitions (except maybe transits with tibbe keyways). I can't speak on EU Fords so I would love to see some examples. I spend a lot of time on international forums because of my work so its nice to know for comparing. But, I think you are mistaking the key buzzer for a dust cover, they look similar on some locks. The focus in original question is one of them. Its large and fills the entire keyway so it would be easy to see it and think dust cover.